# How to auto generate docstring snippets for python modules in VsCode?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, vscode-extensions, docstring

I have installed the Visual Studio Code extension [Python Docstring Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) that autogenerates docstring snippet.

Customized settings that I use:

```
"autoDocstring.docstringFormat": "sphinx",
"autoDocstring.generateDocstringOnEnter": true,
"autoDocstring.includeExtendedSummary": true,
"autoDocstring.guessTypes": true,
"autoDocstring.customTemplatePath": ".vscode/sphinx.mustache",
```

However, it is mostly useful for function's docstring.

How can I also generate:

- docstring for modules and scripts: entered in the beginning of the module
- packages: Added to the `__init__.py` file
- classes

Any idea in this regard?

Comment: It doesn't do that: "Visual Studio Code extension to quickly generate docstrings for python **functions**."

Comment: There's nothing to generate for classes and modules, just type the docstring text, surrounded by `"""`. Or what exactly did you expect it to generate?